# SSMS - executing two ALTER table statements concurrently for same table

Tags: script, ssms

Are there known issues with executing two ALTER table scripts for the same table? Both scripts alter the datatype for one (but different) column in a table?

I'm wondering if one script finishing and committing the changes it made to the table causes issue to the other script. Obviously, it would be better to create one script that alters the datatype for the two columns together, but that's not how the system is designed.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from the book SQL Server Concurrency,
Chapter 3: Advanced Locking Concepts,
by Kalen Delaney, about the lock type used for schema updates:

> **Sch-M: schema modification lock**
>
> SQL Server acquires a Sch-M lock when performing certain DDL operations that
> change a table's definition (its schema). These operations include adding and dropping
> columns from the table, or changing a column's data type. **Sch-M locks are the least
> compatible lock mode and a request for every other mode will block on a Sch-M lock**,
> and vice versa; a session cannot get a Sch-M lock if any other session has any
> other lock on the table.
> In other words, when a session is making a schema change to a table, no
> other sessions can do anything with the table.

This means that the two scripts cannot execute in parallel: One of them
will lock the table first, so the second one will wait for the schema
modification lock on the table to be released.
The two scripts are therefore serialized and both will succeed,
one after the other.

While correct, this means that the table in unavailable for updates or query
for the duration of the two scripts, therefore doubling the time for it being
locked from all other operations.